# CouchDB _replicator database requires a password for the local target?

Tags: couchdb

I'm using the CouchDB `_replicator` database and am surprised to find that I have to put a full URL to localhost:5984 with username and password in the "target" field; just the database name by itself doesn't work. Does CouchDB just work this way or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of CouchDB's real power is the consistency of its approach. Replication just uses standard REST/HTTP(S) requests to do its work. That's why it's so easy to replicate locally or across the world.

The only gotcha here is that CouchDB cheats slightly for (unsecured) local DBs by allowing you to provide just the DB name, not a full URL - although the actual replication calls prepend the rest of the URL to the DB name and go through the same process as any other request.

So, think of replication the same as you'd think of `curl` from the command line of your local machine, that way having to provide the auth credentials should feel more intuitive.